# Query for "Where ExamDate <= ResultDate or ResultDate is missing"

Tags: sql, date, missing-data

What is the query to find the cases where ExamDate is earlier than ResultDate or ResultDate is missing?

I tried `Where ExamDate <= ResultDate or ResultDate is Null`, but it conflicts with other categories.

Comment: _conflicts with other categories_? Show us some sample data, the current (unwanted) result, and also the desired result - all as properly formatted text. I.e. a [mcve]. Also add a tag for the dbms used.

Comment: @jarlh I bet its SQL Server. They always just tag it as [tag:sql] for some reason

Comment: @Phil. probably. MS did a great job naming their product as _the (one-and-only)_ SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should be able to simply group the conditions by wrapping them in parentheses...

```sql
WHERE (ResultDate IS NULL OR ExamDate <= ResultDate)
```

Note that I've used the null check first to avoid comparing to null via [short-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) (though this is more for readability).

---

The reason your current query may not work with other clauses (eg added through more `AND` and `OR`) is due to [operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Assuming SQL Server, without grouping conditions, something like this

```sql
WHERE
  ExamDate <= ResultDate OR ResultDate IS NULL
  AND Foo = 'FOO'
```

is actually evaluated like this because `AND` has a higher precedence than `OR`

```sql
WHERE
  (ExamDate <= ResultDate)
  OR
  (ResultDate IS NULL AND Foo = 'FOO')
```

Comment: The specified order doesn't guarantee the actual order of evaluation. The optimizer decides it all!

Comment: @jarlh then it's for my own piece of mind 

Comment: Such things can't be overrated!